# How to test limit of available memory (C++)?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, constructor, allocation

I have to check the limit of my PC's available memory by setting values of my constructor. The memory should be allocated dynamically. Example:

```
  class matrix{

    int lines;
    int columns;

public:
    matrix(long lin, long col){
        lines=lin;
        columns=col;
       }
};
```

How to check which values (lin, col) are the limits of my memory? (long type is just an example).

///EDIT: 
"By introducing increasing values (dimensions of matrix) cause the situation when the memory allocation fails"
So the question is: is there any posibility to check which values are the last which can be introduced?

Comment: Bit lost with this. Do you mean your process's available memory?

Comment: By PC's available memory you mean RAM? Or are you looking how much virtual memory you can allocate?

Comment: @Naveen , I think it concerns RAM. So sorry. It's a school exercise, I didn't invent it.

Comment: I edited my post:
"By introducing increasing values (dimensions of matrix) cause the situation when the memory allocation fails" So the question is: is there any posibility to check which values are the last which can be introduced?

Answer (score 5):

> The memory should be allocated dynamically

You don't need to test the available memory - `operator new` does that for you (unless it's overloaded of course). If `operator new` fails, it either throws `std::bad_alloc`, or returns `0`, depending on the version of the operator you [call](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/).

Comment: _" If operator new fails, it returns 0"_ - only if you invoke the no throw implementation of the operator otherwise it throws `std::bad_alloc`

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems will give you as much memory as you want until your process's address space is full. It will not stop when it runs out of physical memory.

This means that there is no way to calculate how much physical memory your computer has by allocating memory, and that allocations will not fail even if your computer is out of physical memory. The latter property could free you from the burden of finding how much physical memory you have in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could trying calling the Windows APIs and ask for how much memory is available using the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function.  See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx